# Who first said that he who cannot govern himself cannot govern others?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, ancient-philosophy

What philosopher said that he who cannot govern himself cannot govern others?

I heard that Foucault said something similar, but surely Aristotle or even King Solomon may have said something similar.

Comment: An internet search brings up several possible sources.

Answer (score 1):

One paraphrase is attributed to the Dutch humanist, [Hugo Grotius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Grotius):

> A man cannot govern a nation if he cannot govern a city; he cannot govern a city if he cannot govern a family; he cannot govern a family unless he can govern himself; and he cannot govern himself unless his passions are subject to reason.

An example attribution comes from [Government in Colonial America](https://books.google.ca/books?id=dpZmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=Grotius%20%22A%20man%20cannot%20govern%20a%20nation%20if%20he%20cannot%20govern%20a%20city%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8-5230pfuAhWioFsKHW-XDRAQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=Grotius%20%22A%20man%20cannot%20govern%20a%20nation%20if%20he%20cannot%20govern%20a%20city%22&f=false) by Louise Colligan, who cites Grotius' 1625 work, [De jure belli ac pacis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure_belli_ac_pacis).